# Undefined function 'lt' for input arguments of type 'cell'. in using cell

Tags: matlab, cell

My teacher asked us to write a program for Huffmam Coding in MATLAB, but I met a problem:

> Undefined function 'lt' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
>
> Error in work5455 (line 49)

Which is this line:

```
if(cell{k+1}(1)<cell{k}(1)&&cell{k}(2)==-1)
```

Since there is no 'lt',how can I solve it?
My teacher is just too busy to answer my e-mail.....
Here`s the code(not finished),thank you very much!

```
fprintf('Reading data...')
data=imread('C:\Users\dell\Desktop\2.png');
data=rgb2gray(data);
data=uint8(data);
fprintf('Done!\n')

if~isa(data,'uint8'),
    error('input argument must be a uint8 vector')
end
f=repmat(0,1,256);
len=length(data);
for j=0:255
    for i=1:len
        if data(i)==j;
            f(j)=f(j)+1;
        end
    end
end

f=double(f./len);

simbols=find(f~=0);
f=f(simbols);
[f,sortindex]=sort(f)
simbols=simbols(sortindex)

len=length(simbols);
codeword=cell(1,len);
huffnode=cell(1,2*len);
for i=1:len
    cell{i}={f(i),-1,-1,-1};
end
for i=len+1:2*len-1
    cell{i}={-1,-1,-1,-1};
end

m=len
%for i=1:len
for j=1:len+i-1
    m=m-1;
    for k=1:m
        if(cell{k+1}(1)<cell{k}(1)&&cell{k}(2)==-1)
            cell{2*len}=cell{k+1};
            cell{k+1}=cell{k};
            cell{k}=cell{2*len};
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Don't overwrite built-in variables such as `cell`, `i`, `j` etc in your code. That'd clean up part of the mess at least

Comment: I guess `lt` means 'less then'

Comment: Don't use `cell` as a variable name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Output of cell{k+1}(1) is a 1x1 cell. Since you cannot compare cells to other cells, you have to make a datatype conversion using `cell2mat` to get the number itself before. Using

```
if(cell2mat(cell{k+1}(1))<cell2mat(cell{k}(1))&&cell2mat(cell{k}(2))==-1)
```

should solve your Problem.
Since cell is a built-in function in matlab I would highly recommend renaming your variable. As @AndrasDeak stated in the comments you might get Problems later on otherwise. In General, you should never use built-in function-names as your variable- or function-names. Please note that `i` and `j` represent the imaginary unit in matlab and thus should not be used as Iteration variables either.

Comment: I'd put much larger emphasis on the built-in part: trying to use `var=cell(1,len)` after defining the variable `cell` would probably lead to out-of-bounds errors.

Comment: @AndrasDeak What do you mean by putting more emphasis? Should I put it in the beginning of the post and leave out the 'even though it will work' part?

Comment: @Max preferably, yes. This is a bit of self-preservation. If we teach newbies in MATLAB that overwriting built-ins is bad, we will get less confusing errors in the future which ultimately stem from overwriting functions; also it will make the OP a better programmer, who employs a more clear coding practise than (s)he currently has.

Comment: Well, it's your answer, it's entirely up to you. I just wanted you to consider that in this case, using `cell` as a variable name is more than just bad practice, it's dangerous. If I were you, I wouldn't put it up front, since the error is due to the comparison, but I'd give a separate paragraph to why using `cell` as variable name is dangerous. But again, I won't hold it against you if you don't:)

Comment: @Adriaan good point! Using `cell` as a variable name for a variable of type cell is like shoting yourself in the foot while running from a killer with a gun. It will not kill you but something else likely will. I would say that in case one really need a variable name `i` or `j` it should be ok to overwrite them (since `1i` is recommended for imaginary unit and the overloading will only be in current scope), but the developer should know what he does and prefer other names.

Comment: Thank you so much guys. I`ve fully understood where the problem is.Apperently, stackoverflow is much useful than a teacher "far away"    :p

Comment: You can't compare cells with `eq`, but you can use `isequal`.

Comment: @horchler well that would work for the 2nd comparison, but is there something like 'isless' for the first comparison?