# Matlab 'main' function isn't reading local functions

Tags: matlab, function

I have a code in matlab (~1000 lines) that constists of about 15 functions. The code runs fine with each function as a different script, but I want to put them all into one file so I can use the publish function more easily. However, when I put them all together my 'main' function isn't recognizing the local functions. Here's what it looks like:

```
function full_function()  
...  
values = fvalues(0);  
...  
end  

function values = fvalues(state)  
...  
end
```

When I try to run it, it gives me

```
"Undefined function 'fvalues' for input arguments
of type 'double'.

Error in full_function (line 32)  
values = fvalues(0);"
```

I've looked all over for how to do local functions and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. If I right-click on `fvalues` and hit 'open' it even brings me to the correct portion of the code, so I have no idea why `full_function` cannot read it. Please help! Thanks.

Comment: As far as I see it, your approach should work. I also did a small test and the function calls executed without error. So I would do a sanity check and check that you are editing the correct file, that you are in the correct working directory and that you are executing the correct function.

Comment: And you're certain that the "main" function is in the same file?

Comment: http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/5200-undefined-function-or-method-for-input-arguments-of-type-double

Please check if this link helps you

Comment: Make sure your main function has an `end` before the rest of the function declarations. It is not required when you have a single function in a file, so MATLAB wont necesarily complain, but this may be causing the problem

Comment: @AnderBiguri MATLAB will give an explicit warning in the case of mixing function definition conventions

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240367/undefined-function-function-name-for-input-arguments-of-type-double), and also try to reproduce this error with as minimal code as needed (by deleting unnecessary parts), and see if it leads you somewhere. If not, post here the minimum code that needed so people can see if they reproduce this.

Comment: I made sure to have an "end" after every function, including the main. It is definitely in the same file. Could it be because there's another directory with a file of the same name as the function I'm trying to call? I don't know how that would affect it though.

Comment: I ran a simple example and it worked. I thought that the clc and clear all I ran at the beginning of the code might have affected it, but it does not.

I think the issue might be from global variables I use throughout the file. I know globals are bad but there was no other option I could find. I'll just publish the files individually. Thank you all for trying to help.