# Undefined function 'histeq'

Tags: matlab, image-processing

[image]I have been encountering an error while doing a histogram equalization of an image. The error is

> Undefined function 'histeq' for input arguments of type 'uint8'

I have the Image Processing Toolbox installed, which should define this function.

[image]

Comment: Do you have Image Processing Toolbox installed? Please create a [mcve]

Comment: `histeq` does take input of type `uint8`. You most likely do not have the Image Processing Toolbox installed. Type in `ver` in your MATLAB command window. Do you see an `Image Processing Toolbox`? If not, you don't have the required toolbox for this function

Comment: Yes sir I got Image Processing toolbox installed

Comment: In that case you've probably got a variable or script called `histeq` that is being called instead of the built-in function. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38240372/1377097

Comment: Please add the output of `ver`, `path` and `which histeq` to your question.

Comment: If you indeed have the Image Processing Toolbox installed, it likely is not on your path for one reason or another. I would run the MATLAB installer again to repair your installation, and to ensure that the Image Processing Toolbox is properly installed.

Answer (score 0):

For record I tried everything to solve the error but could not made it happen. So only thing that helps me is I upgraded by MATLAB to 2018a.