# I'm getting an error "Undefined function 'Romberg' for input arguments of type 'char'." I'm trying to code the romberg integration method

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I'm trying to code the romberg integration method on matlab. I think I coded it right but I'm not getting why I have this error.

**This is the function.**

```
function[t , r] = Romberg (fun, a, b, nmax)
f = inline(fun);
r(1, 1) = (b - a) * (f(a) + f(b)) / 2;
for i = 1 : nmax
    h(i) = (b-a) /2^(i) ;
   m = 0;
    for k = 1 : (2^(i))-1
        m = m + f (a+k*h(i));
    end
    r(i + 1, 1) = (h(i) / 2) * (f(a) + f(b) + 2*m);
    for j = 2 : i
        r(i, j) = r(i, j-1) + (r(i, j-1) - r(i - 1, j - 1)) / (4^(j-1) - 1);
    end
end
t = r (i, j)
```

**This is its call**

```
clc; clear all; close all;
a = 0;
b = pi;
nmax = 3;
fun ='sin (x)'  ;
[t, r]= Romberg (fun, a, b, nmax)
```

**And this is the error:**
Undefined function 'Romberg' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Comment: It runs in R2016a. In what version of MATLAB are you running this? BTW, `inline` is deprecated, use [anonymous functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) instead.

Comment: So I'm having an error because I don't have R016a? My version is R2014b.

Comment: So I used anonymous functions and now it is giving me this error: Undefined function 'Romberg' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'.

Comment: Are you sure that the Romberg.m file is accessible by the one that calls it? I mean are both files in very same folder, or is Romberg.m in a folder that is added to MATLAB's search path?

Comment: What I did is that I created the 2 scripts, wrote the codes then saved them both as .m files in the same folder.

Comment: I suspect that somehow your main script [does not see the Romberg.m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240367/undefined-function-function-name-for-input-arguments-of-type-double). Make sure that it does exist calling `which Romberg` from both command line, and the main script.

Comment: It worked after deleting the folder that I saved my codes in and resaving them in a new folder.